# ffmpeg encoded mp4 with faststart not playing in firefox

Tags: video, browser, ffmpeg

i am having problems getting mp4 files encoded by ffmpeg to play using firefox without it downloading the entire thing first; while chrome plays immediately. I am using ffmpeg to encode the mp4 and applying '-movflags faststart' to make sure the moov atom is at the start, and i have used Atomic Parsely to check the output structure.

I have checked that the server is using byte range etc, all good and other files are working well.

I have compared the Atomic Parsely return from a file encoded using flipfactory that does playback in firefox immediately; its moov atom contains a iod atom that is not present in the ffmpeg encoding.

example of ffmpeg command:

> -i source_file_path -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1024:-1 -preset veryfast -b:v 1000k -ac 2 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -f mp4 proxy_output_path

example of ffmpeg output:

> Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 32, ends @ 32
>   Atom moov @ 32 of size: 6879133, ends @ 6879165
>        Atom mvhd @ 40 of size: 108, ends @ 148
>        Atom trak @ 148 of size: 3567272, ends @ 3567420
>            Atom tkhd @ 156 of size: 92, ends @ 248
>            Atom edts @ 248 of size: 36, ends @ 284
>                Atom elst @ 256 of size: 28, ends @ 284
>            Atom tref @ 284 of size: 20, ends @ 304
>                Atom tmcd @ 292 of size: 12, ends @ 304
>    ~
>            Atom mdia @ 304 of size: 3567116, ends @ 3567420
>                Atom mdhd @ 312 of size: 32, ends @ 344
>                Atom hdlr @ 344 of size: 45, ends @ 389
>                Atom minf @ 389 of size: 3567031, ends @ 3567420
>                    Atom vmhd @ 397 of size: 20, ends @ 417
>                    Atom dinf @ 417 of size: 36, ends @ 453
>                        Atom dref @ 425 of size: 28, ends @ 453
>                    Atom stbl @ 453 of size: 3566967, ends @ 3567420
>                        Atom stsd @ 461 of size: 151, ends @ 612
>                            Atom avc1 @ 477 of size: 135, ends @ 612
>                                Atom avcC @ 563 of size: 49, ends @ 612
>                        Atom stts @ 612 of size: 24, ends @ 636
>                        Atom stss @ 636 of size: 5736, ends @ 6372
>                        Atom ctts @ 6372 of size: 1734376, ends @ 1740748
>                        Atom stsc @ 1740748 of size: 40, ends @ 1740788
>                        Atom stsz @ 1740788 of size: 913320, ends @ 2654108
>                        Atom stco @ 2654108 of size: 913312, ends @ 3567420

example of flipfactory output:

> Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 24, ends @ 24
>   Atom moov @ 24 of size: 561374, ends @ 561398
>        Atom mvhd @ 32 of size: 108, ends @ 140
>        Atom iods @ 140 of size: 33, ends @ 173
>        Atom trak @ 173 of size: 268275, ends @ 268448
>            Atom tkhd @ 181 of size: 92, ends @ 273
>            Atom mdia @ 273 of size: 268175, ends @ 268448
>                Atom mdhd @ 281 of size: 32, ends @ 313
>                Atom hdlr @ 313 of size: 68, ends @ 381
>                Atom minf @ 381 of size: 268067, ends @ 268448
>                    Atom smhd @ 389 of size: 16, ends @ 405
>                    Atom dinf @ 405 of size: 36, ends @ 441
>                        Atom dref @ 413 of size: 28, ends @ 441
>                    Atom stbl @ 441 of size: 268007, ends @ 268448
>                        Atom stsd @ 449 of size: 91, ends @ 540
>                            Atom mp4a @ 465 of size: 75, ends @ 540
>                                Atom esds @ 501 of size: 39, ends @ 540
>                        Atom stts @ 540 of size: 24, ends @ 564
>                        Atom stsc @ 564 of size: 22324, ends @ 22888
>                        Atom stsz @ 22888 of size: 234212, ends @ 257100
>                        Atom stco @ 257100 of size: 11348, ends @ 268448

i am not sure that adding the iod atom will resolve the issue, but thats all i can see that is different. I cannot however find anything in the ffmpeg documentation that seems to help.

any recommendations for resolving using ffmpeg would be great.

Comment: Try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. If that doesn't work show the complete ffmpeg console output from your command (and format it as *code* instead of a *quote*).

Comment: thanks Mr Beard, that resolved my problem. (i dont seem to be able to mark the answer, maybe because i am brand new)